# Webpack 2 pug - не работает require

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, pug

В общем, есть webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const PATHS = {
    source: path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
    dist: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    assets: 'assets/'
};

const PAGES_DIR = `${PATHS.source}/public/pages/`;
const PAGES = fs.readdirSync(PAGES_DIR).filter(fileName => fileName.endsWith('.pug'));

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        entry: PATHS.source + "/app/index.js",
        output: {
            path: PATHS.dist,
            filename: "[name].js"
        },
        plugins: [
            ...PAGES.map(page => new HtmlWebpackPlugin ({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/${page}`,
                filename: `./${page.replace(/\.pug/,'.html')}`
            }))
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.pug$/,
                    loaders: [
                        {
                            loader: "html-loader"
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "pug-html-loader",
                            options: {
                                "pretty":true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options:{
                        name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
                        outputPath :  PATHS.assets,
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: PATHS.source + "/public",
            port: 7800
        }
    }
};
```

Пытаюсь в pug файле использовать require:

```
img(src=require("../images/cat.jpg"))
```

На что webpack выдаёт ошибку:

```
 ERROR in ./src/public/pages/index.pug (./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/public/pages/index.pug)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/pug-html-loader/lib/index.js):
    TypeError: require is not a function
```

Так же я пробовал делать вот так:

```
- let cat = require("../images/cat.jpg")
  img(src=cat)
```

Но результат не меняется

А если я прописываю путь без require - то на выходе получается вот что:

```
<img src="[object Module]">
```

Comment: какой-то странный лоадер для `pug`, я такого не видел. он у Вас раньше нормально работал?

Comment: Да, он может работать сразу для нескольких страниц - проблема только в картинках)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

только что нашел Вашу проблему для **pug-html-loader** [на репозитории пакета](https://github.com/willyelm/pug-html-loader/issues/36)

> **update** с решением проблемы с **pug-loader**

вставьте этот новый конфиг **pug** для *вебпака*:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
            esModule: false,
         },
    }
}
```

ошибка была в том, что по умолчанию `webpack` использовал новую **es** систему модулей. с добавлением опции `esModule: false` в `url-loader` теперь не нужно каждый раз дописывать `default` к `require`. всё работает отлично.

еще одна причина в том, что Вы по ошибке неправильно указали путь к картинке, исходя из Вашей файловой структуре проекта (забыли папку **public** добавить). правильный путь будет такой:

```
img(src=require("../../public/images/cat.jpg"))
```

на всякий случай дублировал решение проблемы в Ваш репозиторий. вот [ссылка](https://github.com/Golandec88/pug-bug/issues/1) на неё

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но можно ли как нибудь без создания переменных обойтись? Я в комментарии выше, описал

Comment: @Golandec88, а с **pug-loader** `img(src=require("../images/cat.jpg"))` не работает?

Comment: На выходе получается вот это:
```<img src="{"default":"assets/cat.7d4ee3103bc1da2a213fbf39ceec8007.jpg"}">```

Comment: Нашел решение) Но кажется, всё равно не правильное:
```img(src=require("../images/cat.jpg").default)```

Comment: @Golandec88, эта ошибка происходит из-за неточной настройки **file-loader**, который отвечает за обработку Ваших изображений. лично я не образован в его настройках, но я бы посоветовал для изображений попробовать `url-loader`

Comment: С url-loader'ом ничего не изменилось( И ещё, я заметил одну проблему
Вот структура проекта:
https://prnt.sc/rc35x3
Если я пытаюсь вызвать require внутри компонента test - то выходит ошибка что картинка не найдена внутри той папки где лежит компонент. Искал что то вроде алиасов для pug - но не помогло.

Comment: @Golandec88, скиньте скриншотом как Вы подключили `ulr-loader` в **webpack**

Comment: Вот как я подключил url-loader:
https://prnt.sc/rc3bib

Comment: @Golandec88, жесть какая-то. тогда я не предполагаю какая здесь может быть причина. скиньте тогда git проекта, я в живую посмотрю

Comment: https://github.com/Golandec88/pug-bug
Вот репозиторий, заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: @Golandec88, не поверите, но я решил Вашу проблему с `require`. Вам сюда написать или на **git** сделать *PullRequet*?

Comment: Мне было бы удобнее тут, если Вас не затруднит)

Comment: @Golandec88, поправил свой публичный ответ, там всё описание. если не получилось - отпишите еще раз. если же всё заработает - утвердите мой ответ как правильный

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо Вам большое за ответ! Этот способ кстати с file-loader тоже работает!

Answer (score 0):

Я смог решить эту проблему таким вот способом, не знаю правильно это или нет - но работает)

В webpack.config.js я изменил загрузчик для pug:

```
{
  test: /\.pug$/,
  loaders: [
    {
      loader: "pug-loader"
    }
  ]
},
```

И в pug файле, вот так обратился к картинке:

```
- let cat = require("../images/cat.jpg")
img(src=cat.default)
```

Если есть способ по лучше, пожалуйста напишите его - буду очень благодарен!

Comment: как раз хотел Вам порекомендовать использовать `pug-loader`) но Вы меня опередили

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но меня смущает что приходится создавать переменную в которую приходит объект - это нормально? Может есть решение по лучше что бы не создавать переменных?